# Django: `not F("is_show")` did not work properly

Tags: django

I am learning Django. When I use `F` to modify the `is_show` field, I can only switch `True` to `False`, but cannot switch `False` to `True`

```py
...

    @admin.action(description='switch show')
    def make_switch_show(modeladmin, request, queryset):

        # This code does not work properly, so I have to use `for`
        # Why this code cannot work like the following `for`
        # queryset.update(is_show=not F('is_show'))

        for it in queryset:
            it.is_show = False if it.is_show else True
            it.save()

    actions = [make_switch_show]

...
```

Some environmental information

```
django = "3.2.8"
Python 3.9.7
Database SQLite
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`F` expressions do not bring the field value from db to Python - they construct a SQL expression to reference the field in the final query.

The reason it can switch `True` to `False` but not the other way around is that for Python the expression is never false - it always returns an object of type `F`.
So `not F('is_show')` is always `False`, because it is equal to `not bool(F('is_show'))` and `bool(F('is_show'))` is `True`. `not True` is `False`

I don't think Django currently provides a straightforward way to negate a `F` expression. You might have luck with [`Case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case)